# Compare two List<DateTime> in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, datetime, compare

I've the following code;

```
'list of dates
List<DateTime> oAllDates = new List<DateTime>();

// Imagine we are adding DateTime objects with the following values.
oAllDates.Add("2013-11-01"); 
oAllDates.Add("2013-11-02"); 
oAllDates.Add("2013-11-03"); 
...
oAllDates.Add("2013-11-30"); 

List<DateTime> MyDates = new List<DateTime>();
MyDates.Add("2013-11-03");
```

I want to get a bool result if any date in MyDates appears in the list oAllDates. I could use the following

```
foreach (DateTime dtDate in oAllDates)
{
    foreach (DateTime myDate in MyDates)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a better way using LINQ that could achieve this.  Also, I then have a list like

```
List<int> MyDaysByName = new List<int>();
MyDaysByName.Add(1); //sunday
MyDaysByName.Add(5); //thursday
```

I'm wanting to find any dates in oAllDates that are a Sunday or Thursday ?

Comment: What is the structure of `oAllDates` ? do you have `DateTime` type property ?

Comment: How on earth you can do that `List<DateTime> oAllDates = new List<oAllDates>();` ?

Comment: I'd suggest to ask your second question seperately, so that other users can be benefited

Comment: But my second question would still be using the same oAllDates  list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var anyOfthem = oAllDates.Intersect(MyDates).Any();
```

Comment: @Tommo1977 Do note that the default comparer for `DateTime` will also consider the "time" part.

Comment: `oAllDates` is not a `List<DateTime>` its a custom object, with same `DateTime` property, I guess

Comment: @Habib Oh right, hadn't spotted that. Looks a little odd to me as the list definition isn't `DateTime`, but the iteration of it is.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, question just got ghost edited, now its a list of DateTime so perfect answer

Comment: @Habib thanks for mentioning, I edited my answer. Edited again because question changed :P

Comment: @wudzik, I believe your original answer was correct, question just got edited. +1 :)

Comment: @wudzik, will this consider the time part ?

Comment: @Tommo1977 yes, it will

Comment: Can I only compare the Date part, plus I've a additional compare I need for the Day of the week by Name.

Comment: @Tommo1977 yes, add -> .Select(x=>x.Date) after names of your variables it will select dates only

Answer (score 3):

Use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
bool result = oldDates.Intersect(MyDates).Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
oAllDates.Any(x => MyDates.Contains(x));
```